# Searching using Solr Sunspot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sunspot

I'm using Sunspot for a search function. Here's my controller file.

```
     def show
        search = Clothes.search do
        fulltext 'params[:name]'
        paginate :page => 1, :per_page => 30

       end
     @results = search.results
     end
```

I've a model where I've products with name, maxprice, minprice, etc.,
The search function is working only if I insert

```
     fulltext 'Nike'
```

But then it displays all the Nike products for any search query.
Can you guys please help me out.

This is my model

```
    class Clothes < ActiveRecord::Base

       searchable do
       text :name, :default_boost => 1
       integer :discount
       float :maxprice
       float :minprice
       string :image
     end
```

Also my view file.

```
         <h1>Results for your search.</h1>
         <%= render "shirts/new"%>


      <table><tr><th>Name</th><th>Max. Price</th><th>Min. Price</th><th>Discount</th><th>Image</th></tr>

    <% for prod in @results %>
    <tr><td><%= prod.name %></td><td><%= prod.maxprice%></td><td><%= prod.minprice%></td><td><%= prod.discount%></td><td> <%= image_tag(prod.image, :alt => "logo", :size => "75x75") %> </td></tr>

          <% end %>
          </table>
```

Please help me out with this.

end

Answer (score 0):

Try this, i have used this piece of code long time back. It should work

```
      search = Sunspot.search(Food) do
       keywords reference if reference.present?
       with(:vendor_id).any_of(vendor_ids) if vendor_ids.present?
       order_by :created_at, :desc
       paginate(:page => page, :per_page => per_page)
      end
```

In the model, `keywords reference, :fields => [:user_name, :food_habits, :age]

keywords method by default includes all text fields unless otherwise specified by the option`

Comment: I appreciate your help. But when I added your piece of code, it says undefined method reference.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you pass a string `'params[:name]'` to the `fulltext` method rather than the value of `params[:name]` itself. Change it to this:

```
def show
  search = Clothes.search do
    fulltext params[:name]

    paginate :page => 1, :per_page => 30
  end
  @results = search.results
end
```

Comment: Does it do anything different though? Are you sure your models are indexed properly?

Comment: It displays everything in the database when I don't give any input. But when I enter a keyword it doesn't output anything. And when I reindex my database using: rake sunspot:reindex. It displays this: [###############################################################################] [8/8] [100.00%] [00:00] [00:00] [89.15/s]. Is it getting properly reindexed?

Comment: If you don't specify a search query, it should indeed return everything. Your indexing seems fine too if all you have are those 8 records in the database. Are you searching for a keyword that is actually in a Clothes name? You can access the Solr admin interface as well. This way you can see more details of what Solr is doing: http://localhost:8982/solr